# jQuery datepicker: options ignored selecting the text field

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to use this datepicker
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

into the specific I'm using the "component" view, so a text field with a button ar its side.

I've set the datepicker to ask for the year (among decades), then the month and then the day, I've set the language as Italian and the date format as dd/mm/yyyy.

That works correctly if I use the button to select the date, but if I give the focus to the text field, the datepicker appears as the default view: montly view to pick the date, English language and mm/dd/yyyy format for the date.

This is the code in use:

```
<input data-provide="datepicker" class="form-control" id="birthdate" placeholder="Data di nascita" readonly="readonly" name="birthdate" type="text"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>

$('.input-group.date').datepicker({
format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
weekStart: 1,
startView: 2,
clearBtn: true,
language: "it",
autoclose: true});
```

You can also see an example here: http://www.luigicaradonna.it/datepicker/prova.php

try to click the button and select a date, that's how it should work, then reload the page and click on the text field, that's the wrong behaviour.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have you input like this

```
<div class="input-group date">
    <input data-provide="datepicker" type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

You can see the `data-provide="datepicker"` in your input. That's the cause it not working as you expected. I don't know if that's neccesary for you but if you remove that `data-provide="datapicker"` it should work fine.

```
<div class="input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

I run some test with you sample codes and that way works for me. Hope it helps

Comment: No, I don't need data-provide, I added it because on the documentation I read to use it, but probably I misunderstood.